# Laravel eloquent where filter HasMany relationship not working as desired

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know some will say this is a duplicated question. **Wait**, I have a particular situation I haven't found so far on any other post.

I have a User model (User.php) and a Team model (Team.php).

A user belongs to a team. A team has many users.

Inside the User model, I have this attribute (column) "type".

From the Team model, I want to display in a data table the list of all teams with their users whose type is "beginner".

**User.php**

```
protected $with = ['team'];

public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

**Team.php**

```
public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->where('users.type','=','beginner');
}
```

As you can see, I'm already filtering the users I want to display.

Let's say I have the following data:

**Teams**

```
Team one: User 1 (type: intermediate), User 2 (type: intermediate)
Team two: User 3 (type: beginner), User 4 (type: beginner)
Team three: User 5 (type: beginner), User 6 (type: beginner)
```

However, when I get the teams list, all of them are displayed, which is something I don't want.

```
|     Team    |      Members    |
--------------------------------|
|  Team one   |                 |
|  Team two   |  User 3, User 4 |
|  Team three |  User 5, User 6 |
---------------------------------
```

What I want in this case is that "Team one" not be shown. This partially works, since no member is shown for Team one.

I have first tried:

```
$teams = Team::with('members')->get();
```

And then this:

```
$teams = Team::with(['members'=>function($query){
                $query->where('users.type','beginner');
            }])->get();
```

But it doesn't filter out the unwanted teams to be shown.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i always recommend building relations without 'wheres' so you could reuse it from various places for various needs ...

```
public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

then, to get the teams with there members, only the teams who got 'beginners' you
using
[whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$teams = Team::whereHas('members',function($query){
        $query->where('users.type','beginner');
    })->with('members') ->get();
```

Comment: `with`  is unnecessary

Comment: welcome @H.Rafiee , the question said: I want to display in a data table the list of all teams with their users, i quote again (with their users)

Comment: but he said "What I want in this case is that "Team one" not be shown." so when `has` or `whereHas` is enough

Answer (score 3):

First at all `with` function of eloquent it's look like as `LEFT JOIN` on **MYSQL** so if you want only your teams where has beginner users just use `has` or `whereHas` function

```php
$teams = Team::has('members')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
Team::has('members')->with('members')->get();
```

There is also a workaround in order to set a filter on a relationship without using a where clause.

**Team.php**

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function members(){
        return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
    }
}
```

Next, we will create the model "Member" as a child class of User.

**Member.php**

```
class Member extends User
{
    protected static $type = 'beginner';
}
```

Finally we add the following code(*) to the User (only added code is showed, not the whole class).

(*) using [Late Static Bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

The table attribute must be set to "users" so that the Member model also uses the "users" table instead of the "members" table.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected static $type = null;

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $model->type = static::$type ?? $model->type;
        });

        static::addGlobalScope('Type', function ($query) {
            return static::$type ? $query->where('type', static::$type) : $query;
        });
    }
}
```

In addition, it is easier to create a beginner user through the Member model.

```
Member::create(['name' => 'Iggy Pop', 'email' => 'rock@iguana.com']);
```

Since type is seting to 'beginner' by default thanks to:

```
static::saving(function ($model) {
    $model->type = static::$type ?? $model->type;
});
```

(saving method is executed on each insert and update envent of Member).

In the same way, Member::all() filters users by type 'beginner' due to:

```
static::addGlobalScope('Type', function ($query) {
    return static::$type ? $query->where('type', static::$type) : $query;
});
```